# Highcharts cannot read property 'marker' of undefined error

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I am using highcharts 3.0 version. I am trying to add a gauge chart. The chart is generating but i am getting error as 'cannot reaad property 'marker' of undefined.

I am not getting the value of series in chart. Also used highcharts-more.js as suggested.

Please reply what is going wrong

```
chart: {
        type: 'gauge',
                renderTo: selector

    },

    title: null,

    pane: {
        center: ['50%', '85%'],
        size: '140%',
        startAngle: -90,
        endAngle: 90,
        background: {
            backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || '#EEE',
            innerRadius: '60%',
            outerRadius: '100%',
            shape: 'arc'
        }
    },

    tooltip: {
        enabled: false
    },

    // the value axis
    yAxis: {

        lineWidth: 0,
        minorTickInterval: null,
        tickPixelInterval: 400,
        tickWidth: 0,
        title: {
            y: -70
        },
        labels: {
            y: 16
        },
            min: 0,
        max: 200,
        title: {
            text: 'Speed'
        }
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            color: '#FF0000'
    },
    },

         series: [{
        name: 'Speed',
        data: [80],
        dataLabels: {
            format: '<div style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:25px;color:' +
                 'black' + '">{y}</span><br/>' +
                   '<span style="font-size:12px;color:silver">km/h</span></div>'
        },

    }]
});
```

Comment: Where are you using 'marker' in your code? what code you are using to read series data? I can not see any error in you chart. Can you please share code where your are using 'marker' and series data. The chart render perfectly http://jsfiddle.net/6jkb0863/ So there must be some more code where you got above error.

Comment: I am not using it in my code. It is there in highcharts.js.. defaultPlotOptions is coming as undefined

Comment: Then it should work as specified in above JSFiddle.

Comment: the Fiddle looks absolutely fine. But in my case var defaultPlotOptions = defaultOptions.plotOptions,. this thing from highcharts.js is not getting set with 'gauge'.  getting error in this line:  getAttribs: function () {
  var series = this,
   seriesOptions = series.options,
   normalOptions = defaultPlotOptions[series.type].marker ? seriesOptions.marker : seriesOptions,

Comment: @NidhiSolanki The code you posted was used to recreate the issue in JSFiddle and there is no error - http://jsfiddle.net/6jkb0863/. This means that information your provided is not sufficient enough to determinate what the problem is - please post live example, like JSFiddle, that will recreate your issue or post precise information that will allow recreating of the issue.

Comment: thanks for the reply. had some issue with loading the scripts. worked fine